How to use Fourier method to solve the Poisson equation $-\Delta v=x y$?
Suppose that $B_{1}$ is a ball centered at $0$ with radius $1$, consider the equation  $-\Delta v=x y$ and $v=0$ on boundary, I want to use Fourier method to solve it, but the Fourier transform is defined on a whole space, not on a bounded space, and I also don't know how to treat the boundary condition.

(a) What do you mean by Fourier method (series?) As you say, you can't just apply the Fourier transform to this equation (b) is this equation in 2D (as your RHS suggests?) (c) if so the solution is $v = xy(1-x^2-y^2)/12$.

The RHS of the equation can be rewritten, in polar coordinates, as $r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin 2\theta$. This suggests the ansatz $v(r,\theta)=f(r)\sin 2\theta$.

yes, this is in 2D, could you please tell me how to find the solution?thank you@messenger

on the boundary, $xy=\frac{r^{2}sin(2\theta)}{2}$, hence we guess that the solution has the form $f(r)sin(2\theta)$
then substitute this into the polar-coordinates form of the Laplacian and eliminate the $sin(2\theta)$, we get $$f_{rr}+\frac{f_{r}}{r}-\frac{4f(r)}{r^{2}}=-\frac{r^{2}}{2}$$
then we can rewrite it in the form$$r^{2}f_{rr}+rf_{r}-4f(r)=-\frac{r^4}{2}$$
This is an Euler-Cauchy equations!, we need to first solve the homogeneous version, we start by solving $m(m-1)+m-4=0$, which solve $m=2$ or $m=-2$, hence the basis of solutions to the homogeneous version is $u_{1}=r^2$ and $u_2=r^{-2}$, the Wronskian is $W=u_{1}u_{2}'-u_{2}u_{1}'=-4r^{-1}$, hence the variation of parameters tell us that a particular solution is $A(r)u_{1}(r)+B(r)u_{2}(r)$, in which $$A(r)=-\int \frac{1}{W}u_{2}(r)(-\frac{r^2}{2})dr=-\frac{r^2}{16}$$ and $$B(r)=\int \frac{1}{W}u_{1}(r)(-\frac{r^2}{2})dr=\frac{r^6}{48}$$, hence the particular solution is $-\frac{r^4}{24}$, we also notice that the function should be differentiable, hence the coefficient of $u_2$ should be $0$, hence the solution should be $$u(r)=cr^2-\frac{r^4}{24}$$, if $r=1$ then $u=0$, hence we get $c=\frac{1}{24}$, hence the final solution is $$v(r,\theta)=(\frac{1}{24})(r^2-r^4)sin(2\theta)$$, hence $$v(x,y)=\frac{xy(1-x^2-y^2)}{12}$$
